# How can I speed up my calculations with loops? Python

Tags: python, performance, mathematics

I wrote this code. But it works very slowly.

I'm figuring out how many times I have to run the case generator to find numbers less than or equal to inv, in this case six. I count the number of attempts until a digit <= 6 is generated. I find inv equal to 1 and repeat the loop. Until inv is 0. I will keep trying to generate six digits <= 6.

And I will repeat all this 10 ** 4 degrees again to find the arithmetic mean.

Help me speed up this code. Works extremely slowly. **The solution should be without third-party modules.** I would be immensely grateful. Thank!

```
import random

inv = 6

    def math_count(inv):
        n = 10**4
        counter = 0
        while n != 0:
            invers = inv
            count = 0
            while invers > 0:
                count += 1
                random_digit = random.randint(1, 45)
                if random_digit <= invers:
                    invers -= 1
                    counter += count
                    count = 0
    
            if invers == 0:
                n -= 1
                invers = inv
        
        return print(counter/10**4)

math_count(inv)
```

Comment: Why do you need "invers = inv"?

Comment: First, the invers is equal to inv. After the cycles, the invers is 0. And then I again assign the inv value to it

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Please could you clarify. It looks like you basically have a relatively simple probability question, it likely has a closed form which you can use to avoid all this looping.

Comment: @Countingstuff If I have reverse engineered the OP's code correctly, it's doing this: `def math_count(inv, trials = 10000): return sum(attempts_to_get_lte(x) for n in range(trials, 0, -1) for x in range(inv, 0, -1)) / trials`, where `trials = 10000` and `attempts_to_get_lte()` is a simple function that computes how many attempts are needed until `random.randint(1, 45) <= x`. So, one answer to the OP's question is *Use fewer trials for the estimate*. Another answer, as you note, is *Use math to get the answer immediately*.

Comment: Aha, yes that looks correct based on the numbers. And in that case, yes it is simply a matter of working out a closed form for the limit of (attempts_to_get_lte(x) over n attempts / n), from which a closed form of the full expression will follow. Which is simple as for x in 1..45 it's just the expected number of flips of a biased coin to get a tail with probability x / 45 of getting a tail.

Comment: the indentation looks wrong in that code

Answer (score 3):

The code is very hard to follow. Here's a possible refactor to make its intent
clearer. Some key ideas in the simplification: (1) use loops to manage counters
rather than manually incrementing/decrementing; (2) use more
meaningful variable names when context isn't clear; and (3) delegate some of
the complexity to a helper function. The third idea is the most impactful: the
helper function is simple because it does so little; and the main function,
having been relieved of a burden, is simpler as well -- so simple, in
fact, that it boils down to computing a sum over two loops.

```
def math_count(inv, trials = 10000):
    total_attempts = sum(
        attempts_to_get_lte(x)
        for _ in range(trials, 0, -1)
        for x in range(inv, 0, -1)
    )
    return total_attempts / trials

def attempts_to_get_lte(x):
    attempts = 0
    while True:
        attempts += 1
        if random.randint(1, 45) <= x:
            return attempts
```

But `attempts_to_get_lte()` is an easily solved probability problem: rather
than have Python simulate the manual flipping of coins, we can just do a little
math. If you prefer that approach, I believe the following is correct
(probability experts should chime in if I've gone astray):

```
def math_count_exact(inv):
    return sum(45 / x for x in range(inv, 0, -1))
```

Comment: We need a simulation. Simulation gives more accurate calculations. Thanks for your code. I tested it, but it still works slowly, I already don’t know how to speed it up.

Comment: @Pythonist Correct, the edited `math_count()` won't be any faster. Currently it takes about 1 sec. A key question is **how much faster**? The answer – a little bit faster or an order of magnitude faster – affects which strategies are viable.

Comment: @Pythonist it'd help if you add in the question what you're trying to simulate? maybe there might be entirely different route to take?

Comment: @hjpotter92   I have 10 digits out of 45. inv = 10.  need to calculate how many random number generations  need to make on average to get 10 times the number <= inv.  Each time the number is found, the inv decreases by 1.